# Google Analytics tracking code for domain with and without the WWW

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I would like to know if this is the correct way to track the traffic of my .Net MVC website with Google Analytics if the access is from:

```
http://website.com/ControllerName
http://www.website.com/ControllerName
```

The Tracking Code:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'website.com/ControllerName');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-Y', 'www.website.com/ControllerName');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. This will create two trackers, and the second one will overwrite  the first one (if it works at all, since the third parameter is in the wrong format - a domain name without path is expected). The third parameter is the domain on which the GA cookie ist set. If you set it to www.website.com GA will not be able to track visits on website.dom without www.

However you do not need special code to track pages with/without www (or other subdomains), simply set the third parameter to "auto" (unless versions with and without www display different things). You can set "hostname" as secondary dimension in your content reports to see if a page has been called on the www or non-www version.

Better yet (for SEO, Google Analytics is not affected by this) redirect all traffic to the same hostname.

Comment: Hi, thanks! So your sugestion is to redirect website.com to www.website.com at the IIS Level? And Analytics don't get affected?

Comment: Yes, that is what I suggest (along with setting the cookie domain to auto and eliminateing the second tracker). GA will not care, and for your SEO results this will be (if only marginally) better (from the perspective of a search engine your www and non-www versions are two websites with duplicate content).

Comment: Done! I have build a URL Rewrite Rule in IIS so I can Redirect all the traffic from website.com to www.website.com. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [google tag manager](https://www.google.co.in/analytics/tag-manager/) instead of google analytics and you can create tags which would fire your page view when link contains "website.com".

Comment: Hi thanks! I have decided for a Redirect has suggested by Eike, but thank you for your help ;)